# Is there anything different in the compiler files between English and Korean version of Visual C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I need Visual C++ 2015 in order to build parts of a different tool that I need (that is, I won't be using visual studio itself), but I only have the Korean installer available

Other than the language of the user interface, can I expect the compiler itself in the Korean version to behave exactly the same way as the English version? The other tool that I am trying to build automatically detects the presence of Visual C++ 2015 and it is supposed to build itself automatically, but it's failing with many errors. Is there anything different between the English version of Visual Studio and Korean (or any non English version in general) at the compiler level, other than the user interface text? Can I expect both of them to behave exactly same at the command line level?